# Object To Array conversion in Laravel and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, google-maps

I have a problem in my project. I want that my data will return in this format

```
var locations = [
      ['Bondi Beach', 23.779328, 90.333686, 4],
      ['Coogee Beach', 23.815266, 90.359724, 5],
      ['Cronulla Beach', 23.824754, 90.414227, 3],
      ['Manly Beach', 23.804163, 90.456153, 2],
      ['Maroubra Beach', 23.764990, 90.450636, 1]
    ];
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function map() {
        Auth::user()->hasAccess([1, 8, 9]);
         $sites = Site::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->select('siteId', 'latitude', 'longitude')->get();
        return view('sites.map', compact('sites'));
    }
```

and My Javascript code is

```
var locations = {!! json_encode($sites) !!};
```

But It Returns

```
    var locations = [
    {"siteId":"GPBNP1","latitude":"24.01144","longitude":"90.18492"},
    {"siteId":"BHHZH1","latitude":"23.60953","longitude":"90.90608"}
    ];
```

in this format. I did not find any solution. Any feedback will be much appreciable

Comment: What do the 4th numbers represent in your locations array? Also, you are only selecting siteID, latitude and longitude and no siteName in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the format like this:

```js
var locations = [
    {"siteId":"GPBNP1","latitude":"24.01144","longitude":"90.18492"},
    {"siteId":"BHHZH1","latitude":"23.60953","longitude":"90.90608"}
];

var result = locations.map((location, i) => [location.siteId, location.latitude, location.longitude, i]);

console.log(result)
```

If you need the location names for example you have to change your get request.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to this in a laravel way you can use `toArray()`

```
  public function map() {
        Auth::user()->hasAccess([1, 8, 9]);
         $sites = Site::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->select('siteId', 'latitude', 'longitude')->get()->toArray();
        return view('sites.map', compact('sites'));
    }
```